# Actuator for Ignite Health in EmbeddedSpring Ignite Not Starting

Tags: ignite, spring-boot-actuator

We have Spring Boot Application with Ignite being configured as Embedded Server Node .
*When we start the Spring boot Application, Application loads the certain application  specific configuration data from Database.

This was completely working with out any issues.

As part of the Spring liveliness, we created custom Health Indicator for Ignite Cache Status and include in HealthCheck.
Post adding the following code, application is failing to start and unable to get the Ignite instance in Health Indicator

Enclosed Code Details

```
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;



@Component("CacheHealthIndicator")
@Scope("prototype")
public class CacheHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private Ignite ig;

    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
        try {
            builder.up().withDetail("cache", getIgniteCache());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            builder.down();
            logger.error(e.toString());
            logger.error("Exception in CacheHealthIndicator doHealthCheck()", e);

        }
    }
    
    public IgniteCache getIgniteCache() throws Exception {
        IgniteCache<Integer, CacheHealthMaster> dfiCache = null;
        CacheHealthMaster cacheMaster = new CacheHealthMaster();
        tcache = ig.getOrCreateCache("dummyCache");
        cacheMaster.setUuid(12345);
        cacheMaster.setMsg_id("3342");
        tcache.put(1235678, cacheMaster);
        logger.info(">>> Loading cache: Cache");

        return tcache;
    }
    
    CacheHealthIndicator(){
        System.out.println("inside constructor");
    }

}
```

Error we get is Unable to get the private Ignite ig; Autowired. How do we make Healthindicators to start post ignite is initialized

Comment: Why are you using '@scope(prototype)' and do you see ignite server actually start up in the log?

Where is the ignite configuration?  There is no application.yml or are you creating the IgniteConfiguration Bean programmatically?  Either must exist for the bean to be able to be injected